# Second order ODE with RK4

Tags: python, computer-science, scientific-computing, runge-kutta

I need to plot a graphic showing 2 variables, with a second order ODE with RK4, so far i've done this

```
from numpy import arange
from pylab import plot,xlabel,ylabel,show
Qger = 400
K = 20
T1 = 150
T2 = 60
N = 1000
h = (T2-T1)/N
rpoints = arange(6.0,8.0,h)
xpoints = []
x = 423
def df(s,t):
    dTdt = -Qger*t/(2*K) + 172.8/t
    return dTdt

for r in rpoints:
    xpoints.append(x)
    k1 = h*df(x,r)
    k2 = h*df(x+0.5*k1,r+0.5*h)
    k3 = h*df(x+0.5*k2,r+0.5*h)
    k4 = h*df(x+k3,r+h)
    x += (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
pylab.plot(rpoints,xpoints)
pylab.xlabel("Raio")
pylab.ylabel("Temperatura")
pylab.show
```

But that's a RK4 for a first order ODE, because i didn't know and integrated by
hand, but i can't do that  and neither use scipy, so can anyone explain to me how to integrate this function or use RK4 with a second order ODE. The function is below.

This is the function, only T and r are variables, the rest is 0

[image]

Comment: The [scipy documentation for `odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) has a detailed example of the solution of a 2nd order ODE.  Study that example and come back (maybe in another question...) to get help on specific issues. As is your question is a bad one...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the above in a "semi-discrete" form, thats to say dT/dt in terms of only partial derivatives with respect r. If you can then find a numerical or otherwise approximation to the terms equivalent to dT/dt, i.e. the RHS of dT/dt= df(r,...) then explicit RK4 can be applicable.

In this approach, your time stepping method (RK4), is only applied to your first order derivative of temperature with respect to time.